# Error (405) when sending a request from the client

Tags: vue.js, express, nginx

I'm trying to send a request from a client (Vue SPA) that lies in the path /var/www/ (the name of the directory in which the front part lies)
(ssl installed)
type of request:

```
 fetch("https://website.site", {
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify({
      name: this.state.name,
      surname: this.state.surname,
```

the variables name and surname are entered by the user into the form, and their non-zero values are taken from there.
And here is the server part on the express framework, which should listen to requests from the client.

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();
app.post('/', (req, res) => {
    console.log('i have a quest POST')
});
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    console.log('i have a quest GET')
});
const PORT = 5000

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log('POST IS LISTENING')
})
```

the server lies in /root/server.js , I run it with the node command server.js , but when I try to send a request from the client, I get an error 405 - not an allowed method, when I try to change the server port to 443, I get an error in the console that the port is already occupied, since an nginx application that uses an ssl certificate listens to it, the question is: how do I configure the server and the client so that they communicate on any other port, but at the same time the site worked on https, tried to configure proxying in the nginx config, and set the line:

```
  proxy_pass http://website.site:5000
```

I restarted the config, but the site crashed with error 502.

Comment: Probably an issue with [same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy).  Enable CORS to allow requests from your frontend URL and port. [Expressjs instructions here](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html)

Comment: Is the website http, as opposed to https? 443 can-> "occur if you have SSL set on the default Web site, and you remove the certificate, and then try to set it up on a second Web site."